# on permutations of consecutive PAIRS of row elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider a numpy 2D array having 6 columns.  I have added spaces to make the point that the array rows have 3 PAIRS of elements.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,  3,4,  2,5], 
              [4,5,  6,7,  8,9],
              [2,5,  1,3,  2,5],
              [0,4,  0,4,  0,4],
              [0,3,  1,7,  2,4]])
```

PROBLEM:  I'd like to produce 5 new arrays `b,c,d,e,f`, all having the same row count as `a`, that show the PAIR PERMUTATIONS of each row of array `a`.  The order of the elements of each pair does not change, but the entire pairs are permuted.  This array has 3 pairs of elements, so the first row of the 6 arrays would each hold a different pair permutation of `[1,2,  3,4,  2,5]`.

So, the 1st row of arrays `a,b,c,d,e,f`, in this example, may be:

```
[1,2, 3,4, 2,5],  [1,2, 2,5, 3,4],  [3,4, 1,2, 2,5],  [3,4, 2,5, 1,2],  [2,5, 1,2, 3,4], and [2,5, 3,4, 1,2]
```

The 2nd rows of arrays `a to f` would hold the six PAIR PERMUTATIONS of `[4,5,  6,7,  8,9]`, etc.  **It is important that each new set of array rows treats the permutations in the same sense  (ie: order)**.
The 4th rows of arrays `a to f` would all hold the same elements: `[0,4, 0,4, 0,4]`

I have experimented with `np.lexsort`, and I can work with single element permutations based on `sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations`, but I'm really stymied about **how to set up the 6 arrays using permuted pairs of elements**.:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, its not elegant, and I am not proud of it, but this should get you the expected output quite efficiently, without needing to loop or permute.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,  3,4,  2,5], 
              [4,5,  6,7,  8,9],
              [2,5,  1,3,  2,5],
              [0,4,  0,4,  0,4],
              [0,3,  1,7,  2,4]])

b = np.flip(a.reshape(5,3,2), axis=1).reshape(5,-1) #swap last tuple for first and vice versa

np.hstack([a,
           np.roll(b, 2, axis=1),
           np.roll(b, 4, axis=1),           
           np.roll(a, 4, axis=1),
           np.roll(a, 2, axis=1),  
           b]).reshape(5,-1,6)
```

```
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5],  #Matches expected output
        [1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 5],
        [3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2],
        [2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2]],

       [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [4, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7],
        [6, 7, 4, 5, 8, 9],
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5],
        [8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [8, 9, 6, 7, 4, 5]],

       [[2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5],
        [2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3],
        [1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5],
        [1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5],
        [2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3],
        [2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 5]],

       [[0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],   #Matches expected output
        [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],
        [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],
        [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],
        [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],
        [0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4]],

       [[0, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4],
        [0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 7],
        [1, 7, 0, 3, 2, 4],
        [1, 7, 2, 4, 0, 3],
        [2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 7],
        [2, 4, 1, 7, 0, 3]]])
```

Comment: Does the job with quite good speed!  That was a nice way to use np.roll.